# pandas: best practice to create multiple distinguishable types of NaN

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, nan

I have numeric timeseries data in a DataFrame, where individual columns are periodically updated from a live data source.  The non-updated columns are assigned NaN for these latest dates.  I want to distinguish between cases where the data is missing (just n/a for that date) and when it simply wasn't updated (but another column was).  Currently both are NaN

Do people generally use something other NaN?  Preferably with NaN-like properties

Comment: I would certainly use `None` instead of NaN for unavailable data. You can define your own sentinel `NotUpdated = object()` for the second case, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Why use None for unavailable data?  I'm looking for solutions that would take advantage of NaN's ability to work with numerical functions

Comment: I was thinking NaN was only for propagating errors resulting from calculations, but it seems IEEE754 does allows for this use as well. One suggestion might be to construct special NaNs with application-specific payloads. For instance, `not_updated = struct.pack("f", '\x01\x00\xc0\x7f')` creates a NaN value that is distinct from both `float('nan')` and `float('-nan')`, but I think you would need to unpack the value and examine the byte string to distinguish it from any other NaN.